# Как реализовать боковой слайдер как на домофонде?

Tags: python, yandex-maps-api

Каким образом реализовать [боковой слайдер с квартирами как на Домофонде](https://www.domofond.ru/karta?SearchType=ForSale&AreaTypeDescription=c1514&PropertyType=Apartment&Rooms=Four%2CFive%2CSix%2CSeven%2CEight%2CNine%2CMoreThan9&Mapped=True)?

Мои предположения. Отсортировать свои имеющиеся данные по квартирам с помощью python-скрипта (back-end на нем), сгенерировать html и подгрузить в iframe и так каждый раз.

Данные хранятся в таком виде (json, работаю с API Yandex Maps):

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "Студия, 30 м², 7/9 эт.",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    53.647117,
                    55.973675
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "weight": 47333,
                "square": 30.0,
                "price_meter": 47333,
                "price_all": 1420000,
                "floor": 7,
                "types_object": 2,
                "iconCaption": "Студия, 30 м², 7/9 эт.",
                "balloonContentHeader": "Студия, 30 м², 7/9 эт.",
                "balloonContentBody": "Цена на метр: 47333 р.</br>Цена за все: 1420000 р.</br>Площадь: 30.0 кв. м.</br>Этаж: 7<br>Адрес:  Кочетова 31а "
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на пример в ответе на [аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751333). В вашем случае изменится верстка элементов списка. Данные у вас уже есть в `properties` гео-объекта, так что новую верстку для боковой панели вы можете сгенерировать прямо в браузере, не делая лишний запрос на сервер.

---

Если же вы используете `ObjectManager`, то логик выборки объектов в видимой области будет немного отличная от `GeoQueryResult.searchIntersect`:

```js
// В objects будет массив с вашими JSON-описаниями объектов.
var objects = objectManager.overlays.getAll()
  .map(function(overlay) { return objectManager.overlays.getId(overlay); })
  .map(function(id) { return objectManager.objects.getById(id); });
```

Answer (score 1):

На Фронтэнде подключайся к методу [boundschange](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#event-boundschange).
При срабатывании выполняешь ajax на бакэнд и получаешь массив features, который отфильтруешь по заданным рамкам.

В событии success аякса напиши небольшой код, который продублирует точки на карте на div сбоку.

Comment: Я не совсем корректно сформулировал вопрос. Речь идет о сортировке и выводе отсортированного списка объектов.

Comment: по какому критерию сортировать?

Comment: Стандартно: цена, этаж, дата публикации и т.д.

Comment: на фронте сортируются вполне быстро. попробуйте ангулар